# protected tortoiseSVN repository on web server

Tags: svn

Im very new to SVNs and I came across one problem: how to set up repository on web server so it is accessible on port 80 (because other ports are closed) but it has to be password protected. How to configure this? Could I just put repository on web server then make it accessible through url and password protect it with apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to **basic SVN http authentification with apache** :
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s04.html

You will find the Basic Apache Configuration, Authentication Options, Authorization Options ... well, every thing you need ;)

**UPDATE**

Latest version:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html

Comment: [Fresh version](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) of doc is better choice